# Array min and max values as $lte $gte

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array e.g [3,4]. I would then like to search my objectArray to see if any numbers in my array, match a bed range(from -> to) in the objectArray. Only one of the numbers in my array need to match.

```
var objectArray = 
[
    {
        id: 1,
        customRange: {
            bed: {
                from: 2,
                to: 4
            }
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        customRange: {
        bed: {
            from: 1,
            to: 5
        }
    }
    },
        {
            id: 3,
            customRange: {
            bed: {
                from: 1,
                to: 2
            }
        }
    }
];
```

I don't want to use $where because of the performance. 
Is there something like this? 
Suppose that params.beds = [3,4]

```
db.properties.find({
  $elemMatch: {
    "customRange.bed.from": {$gte: {$in: params.beds}},
    "customRange.bed.to": {$lte: {$in: params.beds}}
  }
})
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What object key are you wanting to match [3,4]? The id or the bed from to?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm looking for the beds.

Comment: Did not realise you were meaning mongo, can you just simplify your query above and just use db.properties.findOne({ "customRange.bed.from": { $in: params.beds }}); ? findOne will only return the first match.

Comment: @Spangle Thanks for editing and sorry for my English

Comment: You can  use this query `db.properties.find({
  $or: [
    { "customRange.bed.from": { $in: params.beds }},
    { "customRange.bed.to":  { $in: params.beds }}
  ]
})`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet This won't work, What if "customRange.bed.from" = 2, "customRange.bed.to" = 5 and you want to search for [3,4,6] ? it returns you nothing

Comment: Is there any issue with the posted answer?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet GREAT! that works, thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query using [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$or": [
      { "$gte": ["$customRange.bed.from", { "$min": [3, 4, 6] }] },
      { "$lte": ["$customRange.bed.from", { "$max": [3, 4, 6] }] },
      { "$gte": ["$customRange.bed.to", { "$min": [3, 4, 6] }] },
      { "$lte": ["$customRange.bed.to", { "$max": [3, 4, 6] }] }
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[Some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)**

```js
let data = [{ id: 1, customRange: {  bed: { from: 2,to: 4}}},{id: 2,customRange: { bed: { from: 1, to: 5 }}},{id: 3,customRange: { bed: { from: 1, to: 2 }}}]

let search = [3,4]

let op = data.filter(( {customRange: {bed: {from, to }}} ) => {
    return search.some(e => e >= from && e <= to)
  })
  
  console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in conjuntion with [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) to check if we could find an item that satisfies the mentioned condition:

```js
const input = [
  {
    id: 1,
    customRange: {bed: {from: 2, to: 4}}
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    customRange: {bed: {from: 1, to: 5}}
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    customRange: {bed: {from: 1, to: 2}}
  }
];

let searchBeds = [3, 4];

let res = input.filter(
    ({customRange}) => searchBeds.find(
        x => (x >= customRange.bed.from) && (x <= customRange.bed.to)
    )
);

console.log(res);
```